# What's the fastest frigate to manually move cargo on 20+ jumps trips?

Tags: eve-online

I want to move small cargo (frigate size cargo) the fastest way using manual gate jumping (no auto-pilot).

I'm thinking the classic moving speed is not what I'm looking for (answered in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64492/what-is-the-fastest-frigate-in-eve-after-fittings-and-skills)) because I'll be only jumping (and warping) from system to system and not flying the ship around.

I'm thinking warp drive speed but I don't know how to affect this (rigs, implants and modules)?

Am I right? If so what ship would it be?

Comment: you'll want a combination of align time (lower is better) and warp speed (higher is better) if you're taking "travelling to the gate" out of the equation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The important factors are align time and warp speed, but align time is the more important one. [A ship's maximum warp speed affects how quickly it reaches that speed.](http://community.eveonline.com/news/dev-blogs/warp-drive-active)

The fastest aligning and warping ship class are fleet interceptors (Ares, Stiletto, Raptor and Malediction) with a base warp speed of 8 AU and align times of a bit more than three seconds. If you transport cargo of any significant value I would recommend a Covert Ops ship (Anathema, Buzzard, Helios and Cheetah), which has an identical warp speed but higher align time of around 5 seconds. The Covert Ops cloak that those ships can fit makes it nearly impossible to get caught outside of 0.0 space in bubbles.

If you can't fly those, use an attack frigate (Slasher, Condor, Atron and Executioner). They have very low align times (<3 seconds), but a lower warp speed at 5 AU/s. But as T1 frigates they require almost no skills to fly.

The modules you want to use are Nanofiber Internal Structure II for better align times. Inertia stabilizers give a larger bonus, but also increase your signature radius. For better warp speed you want Hyperspatial Velocity Optimizer rigs.

I want to emphasize that if you transport valuable cargo, you have to follow the usual safety precautions and use undock and dock bookmarks to avoid being ganked. Someone *will* scan your ship and notice if you carry something valuable, and the ships I mentioned have nearly no tank at all.

Comment: Since the new Rubicon patch a ship's maximum warp speed affects how quickly it reaches that speed. http://community.eveonline.com/news/dev-blogs/warp-drive-active

Comment: From the Christmas gift this year... the Minmatar Leopard with it's Warp Factor of x20 is probably fastest for very small packages (10m3 and down).

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since this question was asked. Nowadays if you don't need a lot of cargo space it's best to use Interceptors. They almost instantly warp. Be careful though, especially when traveling in low sec, several pipes are camped by smart bombing gangs. They'll kill your interceptor almost instantly and pod you at the same time.

Interceptors are by far the most preferred way to travel null sec fast

Comment: Eh, would you really want an Interceptor over a covert-ops frigate in low/null sec?

Comment: Yes, time is money and interceptors can't be bubbled, align time is almost zero. The risk with a bomber is higher because they need to slowboat out of the bubble

Comment: Oh, wow. I didn't know Interceptors were immune to bubbles. I've only recently started playing again after a few years off and didn't know that bubble immunity was added to them. Nice.